# How differents password redirect to differents pages in php and html

Tags: arrays, redirect, passwords

How can I redirect with password to differents pages with differents passwords.
The echo is missing something and I guess I should add an array. How echo multiples echos... Grrr
I have 3 passwords and want to redirect to 3 differents pages with those passwords??

```
<?php
// Rename this file to config.php

$password05 = "fogy05";
$password10 = "fogy10";
$password20 = "fogy20";
$redirect05 = "download/05/index.html";
$redirect10 = "download/10/index.html";
$redirect20 = "download/20/index.html";

$require_https = true;
```

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

if ($require_https && (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on')) {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
        header(sprintf(
            'Location: https://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        ));
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['password'] === $password05) {
        $success = true;
    }
    elseif (strlen($_POST['password05']) == 0) {
        $alert = "Password cannot be empty.";
    }
    else {
        $alert = "Password incorrect. Please try again.";
    }
}

?>

    <?php if ($success) { ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=<?php echo $redirect ?>"><?php } ?>

        <form class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST">
            <?php if ($success) { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Code valide. Redirection...</b></div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <?php if(isset($alert)) { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b><?php echo $alert ?></b></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Veuillez entrer votre code</h2>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Go</button>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (isset($_POST['password'])) {

    if ($_POST['password'] === $password05) {
        header("Location: {$redirect05}");
        exit;
    } 

    elseif ($_POST['password'] === $password10) {
        header("Location: {$redirect10}");
        exit;
    } 
    
    elseif ($_POST['password'] === $password20) {
        header("Location: {$redirect20}");
        exit;
    }

    elseif (strlen($_POST['password']) == 0) {
        $alert = "Password cannot be empty.";
    }

    else {
        $alert = "Password incorrect. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

You can use [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect